# Show modal content only on print preview

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to print the modal content only by clicking the print button

```
<div id="pvmodal" class="modal fade"></div>

 <div class="modal-footer">
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="printbtn" 
 class="printbtn"> Print</button>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`$('#printbtn').click(function(){$('#pvmodal').modal('show')})`

Comment: Also you need to remove any element which has these attributes `data-toggle="modal" data-target="#pvmodal"`

Comment: my modal won't pop out, my print button is inside the modal

Comment: Then trigger the print button from outside

Comment: Actually what is the need of that? This is like locking the house from outside and throwing the key inside

Comment: hang on i have changes to do

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

inorder to show the modal, you will need to place a button outside the modal.

```
<button type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#pvmodal">Open Modal</button>
```

Also, if you are using bootstrap, please also include these in your header:

```
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

For more information, check here:
https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_modal.asp

Answer (score 0):

What about controlling it with `@media` of CSS?. e.g.,

```css
@media screen {
  .print {
    display:none;
  }
}

@media print{
  .print {
    display:block;
  }
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div>you can see this</div>
  <div class="print">
  you can see this only in print preview
  </div>
  
</div>
```